# User interface feedback for product review page

Tags: gui-design, mobile, mobile-application

I'm a novice currently learning user interface design in my free time.

I am currently designing a minimalist product review page for the mobile phone. I would like to get feedback or suggestions on how I can improve it?

I would like feedback on the below following points explicitly:

1. Where should be the title of the product? Currently the title doesn't seem to in a right place in my opinion.
2. What can be filled up in middle empty whitespace if the user did not leave any comment?
3. Is the blurred gaussian background a good idea for the product image?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does the "lorem ipsum" quote stand for the review the user is currently typing?
so when I first go ahead an open this page, this will appear empty but when I start typing "your product is nice etc" this very same text will appear inside the quote??

As for UX my suggestion to you would be - whenever you're designing, you need to think dynamically;

1. The title length will change according to the product, so if a product has more than 3 words title, it won't fit. so the current title position like in your image definitely doesn't look suitable. I suggest you instead double the size of the title and put it like the image attached with left alignment. In that case no matter how long the title is it won't affect your design.
2. As rate matters more than the actual comment, I suggest you place the rate score at the top middle right under the new position of the title with bigger font as well. Maybe even make the actual rating number stand out more, like "4" much bigger, then "/5" in a much smaller font, ie. 22 px and 14px.
3. Now you won't be facing a big problem with the comment left empty, just leave a transparent textbox "or those with underlines only", with faint colored placeholder saying "Leave a review" and a small submit button next to it. If the user did not leave a comment, this won't appear but to the user itself, the rest of the audience will only see his rate number "supposedly".

[image]